# Social media data sharing schemes

Tags: privacy

Facebook is a social media service that allows its clients to share their data together.
What techniques or schemes does Facebook use when allowing data sharing?
Every user uploads personal information about himself/herself. So how does Facebook limit who gets to access this information? Does it use any of the known schemes such as Access-Based Attribute Control or does it have its own data sharing methods?
Also, can Facebook gain access to anyone's personal information in its data centers or is the data encrypted in a way that even Facebook cannot gain access to?

Comment: share data with whom?

Comment: Each individual user with his/her friends.

Comment: `if user in group 'friends': allow`

Comment: Is this if condition defined as a scheme? Or is there no formally defined scheme used?

Comment: AFAIK Facebook does not use end-to-end encryption for posts. Since targeted advertising is (part of) their business model, they probably can and do scan your posts.